# Calculus of Variations: Refractive Index Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vector-fields, variational-calculus

The problem is as follows:

> "Given that the refractive index $µ(r)$ of some material equals $|∇f|$ for some function $f(r)$, show that the optical path length $\int_A^B \mu(r) dl$ between points A and B in the material is no less than $f(B)−f(A)$, with equality if and only if the path is orthogonal to the family of surfaces of constant $f$. Deduce that such ‘orthogonal’ trajectories satisfy Fermat’s principle."

While I have a vague, hand-wavy sense of why this should be true, I'm having trouble constructing a proper proof. At a guess, this will effectively boil down to: "The shortest path distance is given by the line integral of $\nabla f$ over any path between A and B".

I've setup the functional as follows:

$$OP[x,y,z] = \int_A^B \sqrt{(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x})^2+(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})^2+(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z})^2} \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2}$$

I'm vaguely aware that I could try to evaluate three separate integrals, over x, y and z and obtain 6 simultaneous equations, however, I have no idea how to deal with the partial derivatives in the integrand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{equation}
f(B)-f(A) = \int^B_A \nabla f \cdot dl \leq \left| \int^B_A \nabla f \cdot dl \right| \leq  \int^B_A\left| \nabla f \right| dl  \ .
\end{equation}
The gradient points in the direction of greatest increase and is orthogonal to the level surfaces. For a path parallel to the gradient at all points,
\begin{equation}
f(B)-f(A) = \int^B_A \nabla f \cdot dl = \int^B_A\left| \nabla f \right| dl  \ .
\end{equation}
Since $f(B)-f(A)$ is the minimum value that $\int^B_A\left| \nabla f \right| dl$ can attain, this path minimizes the optical path and hence corresponds to the trajectory specified by Fermat's principle.

Comment: @Vpen yes indeed. This is a very general property of the gradient and is not at all dependent on the"physics" of the example - aside from that the physical problem is an example"scene" where the principle plays out.